# Understanding how ConcurrentDictionary works in WEB API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am trying to implement Refresh key repository (JWT). At the moment it looks like this:

```
 public class AuthenticateController : ControllerBase
    {
     ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> refreshTokens = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
    ....
    ....
    ....
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
    {
    ...
    GenerateRefreshToken()
...
    }
    public string GenerateRefreshToken(ApplicationUser user)
            {
                var randomNumber = new byte[32];
                using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
                {
                    rng.GetBytes(randomNumber);
                    var token = Convert.ToBase64String(randomNumber);
                    refreshTokens.AddOrUpdate(user.Id, token, (key, oldValue) => token);
                    return token;
                }
            }
 public async Task<IActionResult> RefreshToken([FromBody] RefreshModel model)
        {
            ....
            refreshTokens.TryGetValue(user.Id, out string savedRefreshToken);
            if (savedRefreshToken != model.RefreshToken)
                throw new SecurityTokenException("Invalid refresh token");
            ...      
        }
```

(I removed the code that I thought was unnecessary to explain)

The user tries to log in, the information about the *first* update key is entered into the collection. I put a breakpoint, you can see that the information is entered:
[image]

After the JWT key has expired, the frontend sends a request to update the key. But the collection is  empty. Why is this happening? I am definitely not clearing the collection before.
[image]

*I think the problem may be that the web api processes each new request in isolation from each other.
How do I solve this?*

Comment: Every request creates a new instance of your controller. You'll need more persistent storage like a database or session store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controllers are *transient* meaning they are newly instantiated every time a request comes in. So your dictionary is wiped out between requests.

To fix this, you'd made your dictionary static, like so:

```
private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> refreshTokens =
    new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
```

Now it will live the lifetime of the application.